# Why the type of connectTimeout property of r2dbc-spi is java.time.Duration and how Can I use it in URL connection?

Tags: mysql, reactive-programming, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I'm using URL connection with application.yml file for my r2dbc connection.
I tried to set `connectTimeout` property but got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.time.Duration (java.lang.String and java.time.Duration are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

and I checked that r2dbc-spi configured the type of `connectTimeout` as `java.time.Duration`. And `r2dbc-mysql`, which I'm using follows it.

Can I use connectTimeout property with URL way? I have no idea how to automatically transfer it from string to `java.time.Duration`.

So far, I saw most type of connection property values are string, integer, boolean. And as I know, JDBC configured unit of `connectTimeout` as `ms` so I could easily set `connectTimeout` with URL. Is there any reason that r2dbc-spi choosed `Duration` type for it?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that from `0.8.2.RELEASE` it parses DurationStr so setting connectTimeout with `PnDTnHnMn.nS` format works.

in MySqlConnectionFactoryProvider.java :

```
mapper.from(CONNECT_TIMEOUT).asInstance(Duration.class, Duration::parse)
    .into(builder::connectTimeout);
```

One thing is, under `0.8.2` It does not implements like this but my pom.xml was importing both 0.8.1.RELEASE and 0.8.2.RELEASE even though I did not define any 0.8.1 things. So spring used 0.8.1

```
r2dbc:pool:mysql://host:port/db?connectTimeout=PT3S // 3 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `jasync-r2dbc-mysql` instead of `r2dbc-mysql`.
[read doc](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-r2dbc)